# Java Mouse Listener

Tags: java, eclipse, mouse, pressed

This probably sounds simple and stupid, but for the life of me I cannot find a way to have a mouse listener which does mousePressed without having to be on a component. void mousePressed(){} doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

Essentially I am making a java program which aims to work without graphics, and does things in the background. So if you click in chrome for example it still will effect the program.

What I was trying was this, which I realize is horribly incorrect.

```
class MKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        moveMouse.playing = false;
    }
}
```

As reccomended I tried the JNativeHook library, however it doesn't seem to work the way I think it should:

```
public class mousepresstest implements NativeMouseInputListener{

    @Override
    public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("worked");
    }
}
```

It doesn't print the text on mouse pressed, am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you please post your code? It's very difficult to guess what you're asking.

Comment: A MouseListener listens for events *triggered by a component*.  IE: it doesn't interpret mouse messages itself; you need a Java component to fire the events.  If you can get a component representing the root window of the desktop, then you might be able to listen there.  Otherwise, you might be out of luck.

Comment: You will not get any help, if you don't show us what you've tried.

Comment: Java mouse listener are only meant for swing/awt components, they are not going to capture mouse events from other apps.

Answer (score 3):

Java Mouse listeners are only meant for swing/awt components and that too from the same running process.

If you want to listen for mouse/keyboard events from other apps use the ***[JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/)***
library.You can install a global keyboard hook and listen for keypress or a mousehook for mouse events.You do not need to use Swing or other GUI classes.

Internally JNativeHook uses JNI to provide these functionality.